# Why does $\pi_1$ commute with almost all universal properties?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I'm studying topology for the first time at college and we just defined $\pi_1$ and the fundamental group. We demonstrated that it commutes with products and enunciated the Van Kampen theorem (without demonstration yet). Meanwhile I'm approaching to category theory for personal interest and I noticed that a sufficient condition for a functor to preserve universal properties is to be an equivalence between categories (path connected topological spaces and groups) (self demonstrated because it's easy). $\pi_1$ isn't an equivalence because homotopic maps get mapped in the same group homomorphism but I was wondering if it was if I quotient the arrows over the homotopy relation.

P.S.: I chose to consider path connected spaces in order to ignore the base point of the topological space.

P.S.: It's my second year at college so I'm at first arms so maybe this question is just obvious or totally wrong.

Comment: I'm taking my time studying category theory so I'm not really good at it yet

Comment: No, $\pi_1$ is very far from being an equivalence between path-connected spaces and groups even after quotienting by homotopy. It also does not commute with most limits or colimits. The van Kampen theorem demonstrates that it commutes with *some* coproducts.

Comment: If $\pi_1$ induced an equivalence between path connected spaces up to homotopy and groups, that would imply that any two simply connected spaces would be homotopy equivalent. This is false; for example spheres of different dimensions are not homotopy equivalent, despite $S^n$ being simply connected if $n > 1$.

Comment: I think there is no category of htpy types, the problem being unambiguous composition of morphisms. I might be way off base though, or irrelevant.